# Guardar campos (Dinamicos) en IONIC?

Tags: ionic, ionic-framework, ionic3

Estoy creando una app mobil en la cual desde una pagina web puedo crear encuestas y  aplicarlas en el dispositivo android
en Ionic Tengo e un formulario de encuestas Que se genera Diatónicamente  (es decir la cantidad de preguntas puede variar  y los tipos}
Los tipos de preguntas que pueden surgir en un encuesta son:

1. Verdadero y falso
2. Respuestra Breve
3. Seleccion multiple

El problema (el tipo de preguntas puede repetirse es decir puedo tener dos preguntas de tipo verdadero o falso)

al momento de crear el formulario  utilizo
`*ngFor`  y luego un  `[ngSwitch]`   con sus respectivos `*ngSwitchCase` para ver el tipo 
(todos los tipo campos tipo verdadero o falso  tienen :  `name="vf"  [(ngModel)]="Form.vf"`  )  => no se como poner nombres dinamicamente con una especie de contador
el problema es al momento de querer traer los datos en el .Ts  solo trae uno,  no los 2

asi declaro el array Form

```
public Form = {
cliente:"",
encueestaID:"",
usuarioid:"",
vf:[],
seleccionUnica:[],
seleccionMultiple:[],
tiempotipo:[],
tiempoCantidad:[],
cantidad:[]
};
```

dejo los campos como vf:[]  para guardar ahi como array

la pregunta seria real mente como puedo hacer que angular/ionic detecte que ese campo es un array?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

dejo el codigo del formulario

```html
<ion-list *ngFor="let preguntas of LocalPreguntas">
      <ion-card >
        <ion-card-header color="primary">
          {{ preguntas.pregunta}}
        </ion-card-header>
        <ion-card-content [ngSwitch]="preguntas.tipo">
            <!-- Respuesta Breve-->
            <ion-item  *ngSwitchCase="1" >        
                <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Respuesta" name="breve[]" [(ngModel)]="Form.breve"></ion-input>
            </ion-item>
            <!-- Respuesta Cantidad-->
            <ion-item *ngSwitchCase="2">
                <ion-label fixed >Cantidad</ion-label>
                <ion-input type="number" placeholder="0" name="cantidad" [(ngModel)]="Form.cantidad"></ion-input>    
                  <ion-select name="tipoCantidad" [(ngModel)]="Form.tipoCantidad">
                      <div *ngFor="let items of tipo2">
                        <ion-option value="{{ items.dato }}">{{ items.dato }}</ion-option>
                      </div>
                    </ion-select>            
            </ion-item>
                <!-- Respuesta Tiempo--> 
                <div  *ngSwitchCase="3" >
                    <ion-list radio-group name="tiempotipo" [(ngModel)]="Form.tiempotipo" >
                        <div *ngFor="let items of tipo3">
                            <ion-item  >
                                <ion-label  color="dark">{{ items.dato }}</ion-label>
                                <ion-radio value="{{ items.dato }}"></ion-radio>
                            </ion-item>
                      </div>
                     </ion-list>
                </div>
                  <!-- Respuesta Si o no-->
                  <div  *ngSwitchCase="4" style="display:block" >   
                      <ion-list radio-group  name="vf[]" [(ngModel)]="Form.vf" required>
                          <ion-item >
                              <ion-label  color="dark">Si</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio value="Si"></ion-radio>
                            </ion-item>
                          
                            <ion-item  >
                              <ion-label  color="dark">No</ion-label>
                              <ion-radio value="No"></ion-radio>
                            </ion-item>

                       </ion-list>
                  </div>

                   <!-- RespuestaMultiple-->
                   <div  *ngSwitchCase="5" style="display:block" >
                            <div *ngFor="let items of tipo5">
                              <ion-item >
                                  <ion-label> {{ items.dato }}</ion-label>
                                  <ion-toggle  checked="false" ></ion-toggle>
                              </ion-item>
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- respuesta  unica -->
                    <div  *ngSwitchCase="6" style="display:block" >
                          <ion-list radio-group  name="seleccionUnica" [(ngModel)]="Form.seleccionUnica" required>
                           <div *ngFor="let items of tipo6">
                              <ion-item >
                                  <ion-label  color="dark">{{ items.dato }}</ion-label>
                                  <ion-radio value="{{ items.dato }}"></ion-radio>
                              </ion-item>
                          </div>
                        </ion-list>
                    </div>

        </ion-card-content>  
      </ion-card>
   </ion-list>
```

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, lograste algo?

Comment: si amigo ya te posteo la solucion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

primero debes crear el array  de respuestas

```html
  public Form = {
        cliente:"",
        clienteid:"",
        encueestaID:"",
        usuarioid:"",
        vf:[],
        seleccionUnica:[],
        seleccionMultiple:[],
        tiempotipo:[],
        tipoCantidad:[],
        cantidad:[],
        respuestaBreve:[]
   };
```

y la forma de enviarlo desde el formulario al array es la siguiente

```html
   <div  *ngSwitchCase="5" style="display:block" >
                            <div *ngFor="let items of tipo5">
                                
                                  <ion-item  *ngIf="items.idpregunta==preguntas.id" >
                                    
                                      {{items.idpregunta}}
                                      <ion-label> {{ items.dato }}</ion-label>
                                      <ion-toggle  checked="false" name="chek1_seleccion" [(ngModel)]="Form.seleccionMultiple[items.idtipodato]" ></ion-toggle>
                                  </ion-item>

                            </div>
                    </div>
```

si se fijan la solucion esta en colocar [] para que los datos se guarden como array

```
[(ngModel)]="Form.seleccionMultiple[items.idtipodato]
```